# Creating an Image stack

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

So I have this 4D numpy array of ubytes of dimensions 100 * 100 * 100 * 3.
I want to create a stack of images. They are RGB images so they have 3 channels. Therefore each image can be represented as a 3D array of resolution 100 * 100 * 3. I am using matplotlib.pyplot.imread to read and write them into the 4D array.

I am writing the images into the stack as:

```
marix[i] = pyplot.imread("path/to/image_i_.format")
```

The problem is when I loop through the 4D array printing its contents using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow, like:

```
pyplot.imshow(matrix[i])
pyplot.show()
```

it doesn't show the images. It just gives black (empty) plots. All the images aren't black.

Comment: can you confirm that `matrix[0]` (for example) has shape (100,100,3) and contains values that are not all 0?

Comment: matrix[0] has shape (100, 100, 3) but all its values *are zero* as the first image is black. But others are not. They appear black too!

Comment: What colour map are you using? [see cmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)

Comment: I am leaving it blank expecting it to default to RGB(A).